# How to append character to a string?

Tags: c++, string

I want to know that

```
string s;
char c;
s = s+c;
```

the following code can append a chracater to a string in standard c++ compiler?
If no, then what should i do?

Comment: It's not that difficult to find information on what the string class can do in C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: You can do that, you can also do `s += c;`.

Comment: you can have a look at string library at [c++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/?kw=string) it has really good documentation also for any further small things about c++ can be found there

Comment: -1 for not trying yourself before asking.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this would work. You can try for yourself to be convinced.